# OO1B character when running example code of quickfix

Tags: c++, quickfix, fix-protocol

I am trying to use an example code of the Quickfix library. I compiled the code with:

```
g++ -o main tradeclient.cpp Application.cpp -std=c++11 -fexceptions -finline-functions -lquickfix -lpthread -lxml2 -lz
```

it compiles perfectly!

When I run the program with the corresponding config settings that the broker provides for the FIX protocol, I am unable to get a succesful LOGON. Instead it logouts, and the FIX message I try sending is printed by the program with a bunch of OO1B characters. Here's a screenshot of the output:

[image: screenshot]

What could be the problem? I have downloaded all the dependencies to compile and run the program (all the libraries to compile the program as well as glibc libxml2).

This is the example code I am compiling:

https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/tree/master/examples/tradeclient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is just `SOH`, it separates each field of FIX message.

See link [SOH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#SOH)

Comment: I see... Thanks for the clarification, I am a newbie at using FIX. Then the problem is some other thing. Any suggestions as to why the "socket error: connection reset by peer" might be showing up? Thank you.

Comment: Your remote peer dropped your connection, as  simple as that. Check your tag 49, 56 pair values

Comment: They are both correct. But I will keep testing and see what I find out... thank you.